# Huge problem when applying texture in directx 9 c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, directx-9

I don't get any errors when I compile my game. The only problem is that it won't apply the texture, instead it applies a color (I know it is weird). If texture has two colors white and red then white will be applied.

Here's my code

```
// Monopoly.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Monopoly.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
HWND hWnd;                                      // current window
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;                                // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;                       // the pointer to the device class
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 buffer= NULL;
LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 i_buffer;
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   600
#define SCREEN_WIDTH    800
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)
float z = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
float x = 0.0f;
float rz = 0.0f;
float ry = 0.0f;
float rx = 0.0f;


// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

VOID InitGraphic();
VOID InitMatrices();

// FVF structure
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z;    // from the D3DFVF_XYZRHW flag
    DWORD color;    // from the D3DFVF_DIFFUSE flag
};

struct textured_vertex{
    float x, y, z, rhw;  // The transformed(screen space) position for the vertex.
    float tu,tv;         // Texture coordinates
};

//Transformed vertex with 1 set of texture coordinates
const DWORD tri_fvf=D3DFVF_XYZRHW|D3DFVF_TEX1;

CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[500];
IDirect3DTexture9 *g_texture=NULL;

// Initilizing direct3D 9
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);

    InitGraphic();

    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(d3ddev,   //Direct3D Device
                                _T("image.png"),       //File Name
                                &g_texture);    //Texture handle

    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);    // turn off culling
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLOROP,D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLORARG1,D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLORARG2,D3DTA_DIFFUSE);   //Ignored

    d3ddev->SetTexture(0,g_texture);
}


//render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

    InitMatrices();

    // set the world transform

    D3DXMATRIX matTran;    // a matrix to store the rotation for each triangle
    D3DXMATRIX matRotz;
    D3DXMATRIX matRoty;
    D3DXMATRIX matRotx;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTran, x, y, z);   
    D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&matRotz, D3DXToRadian(rz));
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRoty, D3DXToRadian(ry));
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matRotx, D3DXToRadian(rx));

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matTran * matRotz * matRoty * matRotx));    // set the world transform

     // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
    d3ddev->SetIndices(i_buffer);

    // draw the Hypercraft
    d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12); 

    d3ddev->EndScene(); 

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

// cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    buffer->Release();
    i_buffer->Release();
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
    g_texture->Release();
    g_texture=NULL;
}

VOID InitGraphic()
{
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), },
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(8*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                               0,
                               CUSTOMFVF,
                               D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                               &buffer,
                               NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    buffer->Unlock();

    // create the indices using an int array
    short indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,    // side 1
        2, 1, 3,
        4, 0, 6,    // side 2
        6, 0, 2,
        7, 5, 6,    // side 3
        6, 5, 4,
        3, 1, 7,    // side 4
        7, 1, 5,
        4, 5, 0,    // side 5
        0, 5, 1,
        3, 7, 2,    // side 6
        2, 7, 6,
    };

    // create an index buffer interface called i_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(36*sizeof(short),
                              0,
                              D3DFMT_INDEX16,
                              D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                              &i_buffer,
                              NULL);

    // lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
    i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    i_buffer->Unlock();
}

// Create metrices
VOID InitMatrices()
{
    // set the view transform
    D3DXMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 8.0f, 25.0f),    // the camera position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),      // the look-at position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView 

    // set the projection transform
    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;    // the projection transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                               D3DXToRadian(45),    // the horizontal field of view
                               (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
                               1.0f,   // the near view-plane
                               100.0f);    // the far view-plane
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection); // set the projection
}
```

UDPATE

```
// Monopoly.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Monopoly.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
HWND hWnd;                                      // current window
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;                                // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;                       // the pointer to the device class
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 buffer= NULL;
LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 i_buffer;
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   600
#define SCREEN_WIDTH    800
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1)
float z = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
float x = 0.0f;
float rz = 0.0f;
float ry = 0.0f;
float rx = 0.0f;


// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

VOID InitGraphic();
VOID InitMatrices();

// FVF structure
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z;    // from the D3DFVF_XYZRHW flag
    DWORD color;    // from the D3DFVF_DIFFUSE flag
    FLOAT tx, ty;
};

IDirect3DTexture9 *g_texture=NULL;

// Initilizing direct3D 9
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);

    InitGraphic();

    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(d3ddev,   //Direct3D Device
                                _T("image.png"),       //File Name
                                &g_texture);    //Texture handle

    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);    // turn off culling
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLOROP,D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLORARG1,D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0,D3DTSS_COLORARG2,D3DTA_DIFFUSE);   //Ignored

    d3ddev->SetTexture(0,g_texture);
}


//render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

    InitMatrices();

    // set the world transform

    D3DXMATRIX matTran;    // a matrix to store the rotation for each triangle
    D3DXMATRIX matRotz;
    D3DXMATRIX matRoty;
    D3DXMATRIX matRotx;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTran, x, y, z);   
    D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&matRotz, D3DXToRadian(rz));
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRoty, D3DXToRadian(ry));
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matRotx, D3DXToRadian(rx));

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matTran * matRotz * matRoty * matRotx));    // set the world transform

     // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
    d3ddev->SetIndices(i_buffer);

    // draw the Hypercraft
    d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12); 

    d3ddev->EndScene(); 

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

// cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    buffer->Release();
    i_buffer->Release();
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
    g_texture->Release();
    g_texture=NULL;
}

VOID InitGraphic()
{
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), 1.0f, 1.0f, },
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(8*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                               0,
                               CUSTOMFVF,
                               D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                               &buffer,
                               NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    buffer->Unlock();

    // create the indices using an int array
    short indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,    // side 1
        2, 1, 3,
        4, 0, 6,    // side 2
        6, 0, 2,
        7, 5, 6,    // side 3
        6, 5, 4,
        3, 1, 7,    // side 4
        7, 1, 5,
        4, 5, 0,    // side 5
        0, 5, 1,
        3, 7, 2,    // side 6
        2, 7, 6,
    };

    // create an index buffer interface called i_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(36*sizeof(short),
                              0,
                              D3DFMT_INDEX16,
                              D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                              &i_buffer,
                              NULL);

    // lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
    i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    i_buffer->Unlock();
}

// Create metrices
VOID InitMatrices()
{
    // set the view transform
    D3DXMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 8.0f, 25.0f),    // the camera position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),      // the look-at position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView 

    // set the projection transform
    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;    // the projection transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                               D3DXToRadian(45),    // the horizontal field of view
                               (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
                               1.0f,   // the near view-plane
                               100.0f);    // the far view-plane
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection); // set the projection
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not use the declared textured_vertex at all and use the CUSTOMVERTEX instead. Because CUSTOMVERTEX contains only color information, it is quite obvious what result you will get :) I'd suggest expanding the CUSTOMVERTEX struct like this:

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z;    // from the D3DFVF_XYZRHW flag
    DWORD color;    // from the D3DFVF_DIFFUSE flag
    FLOAT tx, ty;   // from the D3DFVF_TEX1 flag
};
```

Also change the define of CUSTOMFVF to match the struct:

```
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1)
```

Also the global array `CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[500]` seems to be completely unused, remove it so that it doesn't cause an unwanted behavior in the future. The same goes for the unused `textured_vertex` struct.

Comment: well i did what you said but i still have the same result

Comment: I suppose you also added the texture coordinates to the vertices array definition? Right now there's only position and color, you should put two other numbers as texture coordinates: `{ -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), 1.0f, 1.0f }`

Comment: i did for every single one but still the same result check the new code

Comment: ok the other problem is it doesn't display how the image looks like when it show the image is way different than the real image. the image has some things in it but when it displays it, it shows colors squres inside another squre